# Proof required that $\sum _{n=1} ^N(1-e^{(2n+1) \pi i/N})^{-1} = \frac N 2$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

Numerical evidence suggests this is true, for all natural numbers $N$:

$\sum _{n=1} ^N(1-e^{(2n+1) \pi i/N})^{-1} = \frac N 2$

Can anyone prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider sum of the pair $e^{(2k+1)\pi i/N}$ and $e^{(2N-(2k+1))\pi i/N}$.

Comment: I have thought about this but can't see how it helps...

Comment: @JamieVicary $\dfrac{1}{1-x}+\dfrac{1}{1-x^{-1}} = 1$, for any $x\neq 0$.

Comment: Got it, thanks.